# Using DataFrame.ix with a tuple index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of Pandas code that uses tuples as indices. I've recently come across the need to access an individual element of a DataFrame with `DataFrame.ix`, which is getting confused by the tuples. It seems to think my tuple is a sequence of keys I want to access, not a single keys (which happens to be a sequence) that I want to access. How can I extract an individual row for which a tuple is the key?

Perhaps this is a cautionary tale not to use sequences in a Pandas index, but in my case it's too late.

```
import string, pandas as pd, numpy as np

bar = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((8,2)))
bar.columns = ['col1', 'col2']
bar.index = list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:8]
print bar
print bar.iloc[0].name
print bar.ix[bar.iloc[0].name]

bar.index = [tuple(list(string.ascii_lowercase)[i:i+3]) for i in range(8)]
print bar.iloc[0].name
print bar.ix[bar.iloc[0].name] # Fails with `KeyError: 'a'`
```

Comment: Confirmed that both solutions work. I'll accept the one that uses `ix` since it conforms more narrowly to the question as asked. But is either of the two preferred?

Comment: `xs` may be preferable here.  The indexers (`ix`, `iloc`, `loc`) can do a lot more, but because of the syntax ambiguity between tuple keys and MultiIndex selection, it's likely less error prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the tuple in a list to make this work.

```
In [17]: bar.ix[[bar.iloc[0].name]]
Out[17]: 
               col1      col2
(a, b, c)  0.216689  0.262511
```

Comment: Note that this returns a DataFrame instance and the `xs` method in the other answer returns a Series instance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to do it with indexing, but you can do it with `xs`:

```
>>> bar.xs(bar.iloc[0].name)
col1    0.864788
col2    0.708136
Name: (a, b, c), dtype: float64
```