# How to build a MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame from a nested dictionary with lists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following dictionary.

```
d= {'key1': {'sub-key1': ['a','b','c','d','e']},
    'key2': {'sub-key2': ['1','2','3','5','8','9','10']}}
```

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary) post, I managed to successfully convert this dictionary to a DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): d[i][j] 
                            for i in d.keys() 
                            for j in d[i].keys()},
                            orient='index')
```

However, my DataFrame takes the following form:

```
                  0  1  2  3  4     5     6
(key1, sub-key1)  a  b  c  d  e  None  None
(key2, sub-key2)  1  2  3  5  8     9    10
```

I can work with tuples, as index values, however I think it's better to work with a multilevel DataFrame. Post such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186361/pandas-dataframe-with-tuple-of-strings-as-index) have helped me to create it in two steps,  however I am struggling to do it in one step (i.e. from the initial creation), as the list within the dictionary as well as the tuples afterwards are adding a level of complication.

Comment: So you already have a working solution and would like to improve your code ? Please post your working solution, and use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use `df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)` on what you've created already?

Comment: @Zero its been a long time seeing you. Where have you been ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are close, for `MultiIndex` is possible used [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) method:

```
d = {(i,j): d[i][j] 
       for i in d.keys() 
       for j in d[i].keys()}

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys())
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()), index=mux)
print (df)
               0  1  2  3  4     5     6
key1 sub-key1  a  b  c  d  e  None  None
key2 sub-key2  1  2  3  5  8     9    10
```

Thanks, [Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416113/how-to-build-a-multiindex-pandas-dataframe-from-a-nested-dictionary-with-lists/47416248?noredirect=1#comment81786713_47416113) for another solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): d[i][j] 
                            for i in d.keys() 
                            for j in d[i].keys()},
                            orient='index')

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)
print (df)
               0  1  2  3  4     5     6
key1 sub-key1  a  b  c  d  e  None  None
key2 sub-key2  1  2  3  5  8     9    10
```

Comment: Sir I see @Zero's comment now. You can add his name if you update the answer

Comment: One improvement.  Just `mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d)`.  Similar to how `for k in dictionary...` iterates over its keys not key/value pairs.

Comment: @Bharath just curious why we do not do modify within the dataframe ...rather than in the dict ...

Answer (score 3):

I will using `stack` for two level `dict`....

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

df.T.stack().apply(pd.Series)
Out[230]: 
               0  1  2  3  4    5    6
key1 sub-key1  a  b  c  d  e  NaN  NaN
key2 sub-key2  1  2  3  5  8    9   10
```

Comment: @Bharath also...I just curious .....why we need modify the dict ....personally I do not like reconstruct the dict ,,,

Comment: maybe because its multiindex way of doing it, and it would be much faster than transpose and apply